# pandas - rename_axis doesn't work as expected afterwards - why?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, rename

i was reading through the pandas documentation (10 minutes to pandas) and came across this example:

```
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4),
              index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

s = df['A']

s[dates[5]] 
# Out[5]: -0.6736897080883706
```

It's quite logic, but if I try it on my own and set the indexname afterwards (example follows), then i can't select data with s[dates[5]]. Does someone know why?

e.g.

```
df = pd.read_csv("xyz.csv").head(100) 
s = df['price'] # series with unnamed int index + price
s = s.rename_axis('indexName')
s[indexName[5]] # NameError: name 'indexName' is not defined
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: s.index.name returns indexName, despite not working with the call of s[indexName[5]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the name of the index, and the index values.

In your example, the first code chunk runs because `dates` is a variable, so when you call `dates[5]` it actually returns the 5th value from the `dates` object, which is a valid index value in the dataframe.

In your own attempt, you are referring to `indexName` inside your slice (ie. when you try to run `s[indexName[5]]`), but `indexName` is not a variable in your environment, so it will throw an error.

The correct way to subset parts of your series or dataframe, is to refer to the actual values of the index, not the name of the axis. For example, if you have a series as below:

```
s = pd.Series(range(5), index=list('abcde'))
```

Then the values in the index are `a` through `e`, therefore to subset that series, you could use:

```
s['b']
```

or:

```
s.loc['b']
```

Also note, if you prefer to access elements by location rather than index value, you can use the `.iloc` method. So to get the second element, you would use:

```
s.iloc[1] # locations 0 is the first element
```

Hope it helps to clarify. I would recommend you continue to work through some introductory pandas tutorials to build up a basic understanding.

Comment: Ahh now i got it, thank you very much for your explanation! :) 

Sad to say i can't upvote u yet (<15p), but feel blessed, mate!

Comment: No problem - glad my answer could help you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**First of all lets understand the example:**

`df[index]` is used to select a row having that *index*.
This is the ***s*** dataframe:

[image]

The indexes are the dates.

The `dates[5]` is equal to '2000-01-06'which is the index of the 5th row of the **s** df. so, the result is the row having that index.

**in your code:**

`indexName` is not defined. so, `indexName[5]` is not representing an index of your df.

Comment: I think, I found the correct explanation. Regardless to the fact, that i renamed the index in my code, it's still an regular integer index. This means, that I had just to use s[5] instead of s[indexName[5]]. Seems that the other attempt is only the case, when the index is not the standard one anymore.